# add custom handler with Python logging

Tags: python, logging

I have been working on this almost all day couldn't figure what I am missing. I am trying to add a custom handler to emit all log data into a GUI session. It works but the handler doesn't extend to the submodules and just emits records from the main module. Here is a small snippet I tried

I have two files

```
# main.py
import logging

import logging_two

def myapp():
    logger = logging.getLogger('myapp')
    logging.basicConfig()
    logger.info('Using myapp')
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    logging_two.testme()
    print logger.handlers

myapp()
```

Second module

```
#logging_two
import logging

def testme():
    logger = logging.getLogger('testme')
    logger.info('IN test me')
    print logger.handlers
```

I would expect the logger in logging_two.testme to have the handler I have added in the main module. I looked at the docs to me it seems this should work but I am not sure if I got it wrong?

the result I get is

```
[]
[<logging.StreamHandler object at 0x00000000024ED240>]
```

Comment: How did you get the result?  Using dir() in which module?  If you want testme to be logging from ch in myapp, just pass ch as a function to testme `def testme(ch):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `myapp()` you are adding the handler to the logger named `'myapp'`.  Since `testme()` is getting the logger named `'testme'` it does not have the handler since it is a different part of the logging hierarchy.

If you just have `logger = logger.getLogger()` in `myapp()` then it would work since you are adding the handler to the root of the hierarchy.

Check out the [python logging docs.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)

Comment: Thanks so much! I was under the impression the point of entry would always be picked as the root logger my bad.